# Replace grep command with grep -n --colour?

Tags: command-line

Because I'm lazy.... any time I want to use grep, I want it to be grep -n --colour. Is there a way to permanantly map this?

Comment: +1 for "Because I'm lazy...". Ever considered a career as a developer? :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your $HOME/.bashrc file, add:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS="-n --color"
```

This will work with `egrep` too and in aliases that use grep.

**Update**: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated from grep 2.21 on and if you use this solution you will see the following warning:

```
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
```

The best solution is to therefore follow [maco's advice in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/2189/932). Or switch to using [ag](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/silversearcher-ag), which outputs in color by default.

Comment: respect.

Comment: Respect but no upvote, eh? ;-)

Comment: Aliases can be used after a pipe just fine.  They just don't recurse.

Comment: Hey hey, I upvoted. I like this better than alias.

Comment: @marco: you're right (with bash) - I was thinking of csh, where they can't. Oops!

Answer (score 30):

Edit ~/.bash_aliases
Add a line that says:

```
alias grep='grep -n --color'
```

~/.bash_aliases is automatically included by ~/.bashrc if it exists

Comment: Or add the line in `.profile` if you want it to work in all shells not just bash.

Comment: this won't work with xargs eg: `find /usr/share -name '*.txt' |xargs grep testing`

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the file .bashrc located in your home directory defining an alias, which will override any default setting:

alias grep='grep -n --color'

after the change close and open the terminal again because the file is read only when you open the terminal.

If you take a look on the file .bashrc you will found more default aliases like:

alias ll='ls -l'

alias la='ls -A'

alias l='ls -CF'

Answer (score 1):

Create a script in addition to an alias mentioned in the other answers. An alias by itself won't always work, and a script layer is fast enough for human readable output anyways.

Choose a short name, like `cgrep`:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep --color -n "$@"
```

Place it in your path, say `~/bin` (if you read UPE this is in your path :). Then stuff like this will work:

```
find /usr/share -name '*.txt' | xargs cgrep testing
```

I'm still not so happy, I too wanted grep to always color when stdout to a terminal without selectively typing cgrep.