# how to always use rgrep with color

Tags: command-line, grep

[Replace grep command with grep -n --colour?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2186/replace-grep-command-with-grep-n-colour)

is there anything similar for rgrep auto color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your .bashrc in your home directory

```
alias rgrep="grep -n --colour"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the following lines and modify one line as describe bellow

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
cd ~/bin
wget http://sdjf.esmartdesign.com/files/rgrep
chmod +x rgrep
```

Edit it and modify the line

```
args=${args:--His}
```

To this version:

```
args="${args:--His} --color=auto"
```

Comment: This appears to be a comment on another answer rahter than a complete answer.

Comment: Hi Elder,
Doing like this permit to always use rgrep with color... Wasn't it the original ask?

Comment: Actually the original question  *as I understood it* appeared to be looking for something **similar to** rgrep auto color. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for the modifications, it's clearest.
(I didn't knew the p option on mkdir.)

To complete, if not working (command not found), add 


```
    export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```
into one of the autoloaded configuration file 
(~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or else depending of your distribution)